# How can I resolve the Library not loaded error with OpenSeesPyMac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have installed the OpenSeesPyMac module from 
https://pypi.org/project/openseespymac/. I am getting the following error on importing this module:

```
import openseespymac.opensees as ops
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-bec14fefea3d> in <module>
----> 1 import openseespymac.opensees as ops

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openseespymac/opensees.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openseespymac/opensees.so
  Reason: image not found
```

---

I am using anaconda distribution of python in /usr/local/anaconda3 but it seems like this module is trying to find python in /usr/local/opt/python... I will really appreciate if someone could guide on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when the Python 3 library is missing from your system. On Mac OS, Python 3 has to be installed manually and there are several ways to do this properly:

[The right and wrong way to set Python 3 as default on a Mac](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac)

I recommend “Homebrew" personally.

Note that this error can also occur if Python 3 is installed in a non-standard file path on the system directory, and OpenSeesPy cannot find it. This is the case when Python 3 is installed through Anaconda. OpenSeesPy looks for Python in the directories where system libraries are usually found, i.e., /usr/local/. If Python 3 is installed from Homebrew, or through the installer from the Python website, it should find the library. If not, then you will run into the error that you mention.